# How to Plot the density of Z if : "Z = Gaussian RV + Discrete RV "?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I want to do a hypothesis testing excersise that comes after, **but i'm a little bit confused about the plot of the density of Z**, which i feel i need to understand first:

[image]

More specifically, where do i see in the graph the "P[Y=1]=P[Y-1]=1/2" of the discrete RV? if i am adding a normal distribution to it, with a variance that reaches those limits in the x axis (-1,1).

How does the discrete RV affects my normal distribution in terms of limits?

Side note: I thought about using R to plot it as well, is it a good idea? or should i use matlab?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean plot the distribution function of $Z$?

Comment: The density of Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking for the density of $Z$. $Z=X+Y$ is either a normal RV with mean $1$ or mean $-1$ (variance is $1$), based on the value of $Y$. Let $f(x,\mu)$ be the density function of a normal RV with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$. Then, density of $Z$ is $f_Z(z)=f(z,1)/2 = f(z,-1)/2$. Recall that, $f(x,\mu)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2}}$. When you plot this function, you'll see a two peak curve on your screen. R or Matlab doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you, that's much more clear, I understand better now.